# Android String comparison, substring

Tags: java, android

My Android app crashes during `if` statement and I can not find the mistake.

Here is a snippet of my code, how could I fix it?

```
    public String formatResult(String inVal) {

         String tmp = inVal.substring(inVal.length() - 2, inVal.length());

         if (tmp.equals(".0") == true){

             return inVal.substring(inVal.length(),inVal.length()-2);
         } else {

             return inVal;
         }
    }
```

Comment: You don't need the `== true`, `.equals` already does that for you.

Comment: whats the error message ?

Comment: To figure out crashes, always start with showing us the logs for the crash

Comment: return inVal.substring(inVal.length(),inVal.length()-2); You're going backwards in this line. Your 2nd arg is smaller than the first?

Comment: Sorry, I#m really new to IntelliJ and Java/Android. The whole app crashes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"inVal" can be shorter than 2 characters. Debug the project and watch inVal, in any case put if-statements to control if inVal is longer than 2.

You can change:

```
if (tmp.equals(".0") == true)
```

to:

```
if (tmp.equals(".0")){
```

Another thing is, do you really want to return:

```
inVal.substring(inVal.length(),inVal.length()-2);
```

or you want to return:

```
inVal.substring(inVal.length()-2, inVal.length());
```

EndIndex cannot be smaller than StartIndex. If you want to start from end to end-2:

```
string a;
for(int i = inVal.length; i>=inVal.length-2; i--) {
    a += inVal.charAt(i);
}
```

This should work.

Comment: Hi, I want return inVal.substring(0,inVal.length()-2);. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

`inVal.substring(inVal.length(),inVal.length()-2);`

not very valid since:

```
public String substring(int beginIndex,
                        int endIndex)
```

IndexOutOfBoundsException - if the beginIndex is negative, or endIndex is larger than the length of this String object, or **beginIndex is larger than endIndex.**

Answer (score 0):

```
String a = editboxa.getText().toString();
String b = editboxb.getText().toString();
if(a.equals(b))
    //do something
else
    //do something
```